# Simple Web App using PostgreSQL and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to make a simple web application using PostgreSQL as db with Hibernate, Tomcat as server and Eclipse as IDE.

The user should enter name, surname and country to a simple form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My first Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Let's create a new user</h1>
<form  method="POST" action = "CreateUser.do">
    First Name <input type = "text" size = "40" maxlength = "40" name = "firstname" /><br/>
    Last Name <input type = "text" size = "40" maxlength = "40" name = "lastname" /><br/>
    Country <input type = "text" size = "40" maxlength = "40" name = "country" /><br/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "create" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have AddUser.java as Controller in the Model View Controller pattern

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import model.User;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddUser
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Create new user Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/CreateUser.do"})

public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        /*
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("useradd.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
        */

        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u = new User(request.getParameter("firstname"), 
                request.getParameter("lastname"), 
                request.getParameter("country"));

        session.save(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("useradd.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

And User.java as Model

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "users")

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstname", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname", length=40, nullable=false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="country", length=40, nullable=true)
    private String country; 

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String country) {

        firstname = firstName;
        lastname = lastName;
        this.country = country;

    }


    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {

        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {

        this.firstname = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {

        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {

        this.lastname = lastName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {

        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {

        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Lastly, useradd.jsp acts as view and *should* show the data written in the DB.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My first Web App - New User Created!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New User Created</h1>
<p>
First Name: <% String fName     = request.getParameter("firstname"); out.print(fName); %> <br/>
Last Name: <% String lName      = request.getParameter("lastname"); out.print(lName); %> <br/>
Country: <% String country      = request.getParameter("country"); out.print(country); %> <br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also made the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the /src folder

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firstapp</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <mapping class="model.User"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I can run the application, type in first name/last name/country but, when I press create, it shows this error: HTTP Status 500 - Unknown entity: model.User

Of course it doesn't write anything to the DB.

This is what the console shows:

```
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:2 - Hibernate' did not find a matching property.
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         8.0.33.0
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Windows 10
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            10.0
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          x86
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Antonio\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Antonio\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Antonio\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\eclipse;;.
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 1448 ms
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service Catalina
mag 13, 2016 7:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
mag 13, 2016 7:20:45 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMAZIONI: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [199] milliseconds.
mag 13, 2016 7:20:46 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mag 13, 2016 7:20:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mag 13, 2016 7:20:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mag 13, 2016 7:20:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 1935 ms
mag 13, 2016 7:21:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
mag 13, 2016 7:21:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mag 13, 2016 7:21:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mag 13, 2016 7:21:07 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firstapp]
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
mag 13, 2016 7:21:08 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
mag 13, 2016 7:21:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
mag 13, 2016 7:21:09 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@bfbdad
mag 13, 2016 7:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.AddUser] in context with path [/2_-_Hibernate] threw exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: model.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at controller.AddUser.doPost(AddUser.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've been stuck for hours and cannot find any solution.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you packaging and deploying your application? Where is `model/User.class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Hiberanate 5, please create Session factory in this way:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

instead of

```
     Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);
```

Comment: It worked!

Thanks a lot!

So the issue was related to the Hibernate version? In fact, as you said, I'm using 5.1 final version